# How to split a column into two or multiple columns columns in python using either str.split or regex?

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

How to split this column into 2 or more columns. I've used `str.split('/',2)` to split but it just removed the '/' and did not split into 2 columns.

| X |
| --- |
| East Bound: 6900 / West Bound: 7700 |
| East Bound: 7800 / West Bound: 8700 |
| North Bound: 5000 / South Bound: 4900 |
| North Bound: 7000 / South Bound: 9000 |
| East Bound: 4900 / West Bound: 9700 |

What I want is:

| First Direction | Second direction |
| --- | --- |
| East Bound: 6900 | West Bound: 7700 |
| East Bound: 7800 | West Bound: 8700 |
| North Bound: 5000 | South Bound: 4900 |
| North Bound: 7000 | South Bound: 9000 |
| East Bound: 4900 | West Bound: 9700 |

Even better is if I can have four column headers for the four cardinal directions and filling it with the values from the first table such as:

| North | South | East | West |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 6900 | 7700 |
| 0 | 0 | 7800 | 8700 |
| 5000 | 4900 | 0 | 0 |
| 7000 | 4900 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 4900 | 9700 |

If I have read on the documentation correctly, I believe this can be done with regex patterns but is there an efficient way to do this concisely?

Here is the original df for use:
`df = ['East Bound: 6900 / West Bound: 7700', 'East Bound: 7800 / West Bound: 8700', 'North Bound: 5000 / South Bound: 4900', 'North Bound: 7000 / South Bound: 9000', 'East Bound: 4900 / West Bound: 9700']`

Comment: This is really two questions, as you've provided two different outputs. As to the first; Have you checked the docs for Series.str.split? Specifically the parameter `expand (bool), default False: Expand the split strings into separate columns`?

Comment: Also - why does input have 5 rows and output have 4 rows?

Comment: I have and when i had expand = 'true' code spit out an error. It worked for false. Also the output has 4 rows just because I thought 4 was enough to get the point across for the second possibility but i can add a 5th row for further clarification @JonClements

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer oh it's fine... it just looks odd that you have 5 in but only 4 out... it's not clear in that case given the small sample size if you've just managed to leave one out or you've not mentioned some logic in your question that would preclude a reason for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

For Q1, you can try `.str.split`

```py
df[['First Direction', 'Second direction']] = df['X'].str.split(' / ', expand=True)
```

```
print(df)

                                       X     First Direction    Second direction
0    East Bound: 6900 / West Bound: 7700   East Bound: 6900     West Bound: 7700
1    East Bound: 7800 / West Bound: 8700   East Bound: 7800     West Bound: 8700
2  North Bound: 5000 / South Bound: 4900  North Bound: 5000    South Bound: 4900
3  North Bound: 7000 / South Bound: 9000  North Bound: 7000    South Bound: 9000
4    East Bound: 4900 / West Bound: 9700   East Bound: 4900     West Bound: 9700
```

For Q2, you can try to convert `X` column to dictionary then explode the column into separate columns

```py
out = df['X'].apply(lambda x: dict([direction.split(':') for direction in x.split(' / ')])).apply(pd.Series)
```

```
print(out)

  East Bound West Bound North Bound South Bound
0       6900       7700         NaN         NaN
1       7800       8700         NaN         NaN
2        NaN        NaN        5000        4900
3        NaN        NaN        7000        9000
4       4900       9700         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Didn't know there was an `expand=True` option for string functions, this is better than my version, though I would change `'/'` to `' / '`, or add `.applymap(str.strip)` to the end~

Comment: Thank you! @Ynjxsjmh I guess, I really wanted my second question answered but when I apply your code to my df, i get a error 'dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 1; 2 is required'. Could you explain your line of code for me? Just from initial observation, we are applying a dictionary split across the column but that's where my understanding ends

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer Updated the answer. Idea is that `dict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])` returns a dictionary.

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer does `df['X'].str.extractall(r'(?P<direction>North|South|West|East) (?:Bound): (?P<n>\d+)').reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'ID'}).pivot('ID', 'direction', 'n')` also get you close?

Comment: Not sure which is more efficient, but the second version can also be done like: `df.apply(lambda x: dict([direction.split(':') for direction in x.X.split(' / ')]), axis=1, result_type='expand')`

Comment: @JonClements Yea that gave me a table of all cardinal directions and the values. I have to create new columns onto the original table now with those values is the next issue for some reason. The first solution keeps throwing me an error regarding a length of 2 is required in the sequence element. Not sure what that means

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer I guess you may have some data like `East Bound: 7800 / West Bound`?

Comment: There is no need to use `apply` twice, which can be very time consuming. Just use : `df['X'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(direction.split(':') for direction in x.split(' / '))))`
`

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Yea something a long that line. I thought I had cleaned the data but there are instances like ' North Bound: 10200 / / Oneway North Bound'  and 'West Bound: 16400/ Oneway West Bound' . Would the fix be to remove an extra '/' in the cases with 2 '/'?

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer maybe: `df['X'].str.extractall(r'(?P<direction>North|South|West|East) (?:Bound): (?P<n>\d+)').pivot_table(index=pd.Grouper(level=0), columns='direction', values='n')` - what do you mean by add extra columns?

Comment: @JonClements I should have clarify. I have the original df that has other columns I need to include like street address, date, ect and I just want to break the original column 'X'  into the cardinal directions for the original table

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to use `Series.str.extractall` with a specific pattern to get the direction and the amount, convert the amount to a suitable type (I've just gone for integer here), then pivot_table filling in with zeros where appropriate, eg:

```
out = (
    df['X'].str.extractall(r'(?P<bound>North|South|West|East) (?:Bound): (?P<n>\d+)')
    .astype({'n': int})
    .pivot_table(index=pd.Grouper(level=0), columns='bound', values='n', fill_value=0)
)
```

This'll give you:

```
bound  East  North  South  West
0      6900      0      0  7700
1      7800      0      0  8700
2         0   5000   4900     0
3         0   7000   9000     0
4      4900      0      0  9700
```

This retains your original DF ID's... so you can merge/join back to your original DF at some point.